# How to access env veriables in js file in laravel

Tags: javascript, laravel

I intigrate Stripe Api for testing how can i set public key in env.
How to use in strip public key in js 
Public key:

```
 STRIPE_KEY=pk_test_IS796OfBm2ZFLfvBbwsXHJLK00fE6oqivk
```

and js  file where use this veriable:

```
var stripe = Stripe({{ env('STRIPE_KEY') }});
```

Answer (score 5):

`{{ }}` is a `.blade` syntax control, and cannot be used in `.js` files.

If you have a `<script>` element inside a `.blade.php` file, then it will work, but otherwise you'll need to load the file into JS before including the `.js` file, or get the value via an ajax call.

For example, loading the variable to `js` before including the `.js` script:

`example.blade.php`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  let stripe_key = '{{ env("STRIPE_KEY") }}';
</script>
<script src="{{ asset('js/stripe.js') }}"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

in LARAVEL if you use VITE, you can using "import.meta.env.key_name" for example .env like this

```
API_URL=https://mybackendurl.id/ 
VITE_API_URL="${API_URL}"
```

then in js (before vite build) you can call value from .env , in your app.js
like this:

```
 const baseUrl =  import.meta.env.VITE_API_URL;
```

then the value of your baseUrl  will be "https://mybackendurl.id/ "
after you run

```
npm run build
```

or you keep alive using

```
npm run dev
```